# Email forwarding in Office365

Tags: forwarding, office365, exchange-2013

One of our users has quit her job and didn't wait for the regular one month handover duration. So as a quick solution to this sudden change we decided to forward her emails to her manager for a short time.

On the online exchange admin panel, I've entered the "mailbox features" submenu in her account's settings page. I've clicked the "View Details" link under the "Mail Flow" section. In the "Delivery Options" pop-up window I've checked the "Enable forwarding" box, entered her manager's email into the recipient list, and finally checked the "Deliver message to both forwarding address and mailbox" option.

This is the proper way explained in [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351134(v=exchg.150).aspx) but after sending a test email to this account, the manager's account didn't receive the forwarded email. I've checked the delivery reports to see if there was a problem but couldn't find any errors about this test email.

Has anyone else encountered this email forwarding problem in Office365 before? Could you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that this problem was the result of my negligence. The popup window where I've set the forwarding options did have an "OK" button at the bottom and I've only pressed it and then moved on to test the settings. It became clear that in fact after pressing OK and closing the popup window I had to press "Save" on the former main window. After saving the settings it just worked.

I have to say that the UX designed by MS is not so clear in this particular situation. They should somehow make it more obvious that you have to save the settings after exiting a popup window.